# Type expansion causes an infinite loop in package, but not in project

Tags: typescript, tsserver

I have a small package called `@instantdb/admin@0.8.1`.

Say I create a simple file that uses it:

```js
import { init } from "@instantdb/admin";

const { query, transact } = init({
  appId: "your-app-id",
  adminToken: "your-admin-token",
});
```

**When I hover over `query`, intellisense hangs**. I notice Code Helper is taking 100% CPU, and tsserver doesn't make progress.

#### Cause: Type Expansion

When I look into the `index.d.ts` file inside `@instantdb/admin`, I see this [giant type expansion](https://unpkg.com/@instantdb/admin@0.8.1/dist/index.d.ts):

```js
query: <Q extends Query>(query: Exactly<Query, Q>) => Promise<{ [K_1 in keyof Q]: Q[K_1] extends infer T_1 ? T_1 extends Q[K_1] ? T_1 extends object ? T_1 extends infer T_2 extends object ? { [K_2 in keyof T_2 as Exclude<K_2, "$">]: T_1[K_2] extends infer T_3 ? T_3 extends T_1[K_2] ? T_3 extends object ? T_3 extends infer T_4 extends object ? { [K_3 in keyof T_4 as Exclude<K_3, "$">]: T_3[K_3] extends infer T_5 ? T_5 extends T_3[K_3] ? T_5 extends object ? T_5 extends infer T_6 extends object ? { [K_4 in keyof T_6 as Exclude<K_4, "$">]: T_5[K_4] extends infer T_7 ? T_7 extends T_5[K_4] ? T_7 extends object ? T_7 extends infer T_8 extends object ? { [K_5 in keyof T_8 as Exclude<K_5, "$">]: T_7[K_5] extends infer T_9 ? T_9 extends T_7[K_5] ? T_9 extends object ? T_9 extends infer T_10 extends object ? { [K_6 in keyof T_10 as Exclude<K_6, "$">]: T_9[K_6] extends infer T_11 ? T_11 extends T_9[K_6] ? T_11 extends object ? T_11 extends infer T_12 extends object ? { [K_7 in keyof T_12 as Exclude<K_7, "$">]: T_11[K_7] extends infer T_13 ? T_13 extends T_11[K_7] ?  ....
```

Understandably, VSCode may be suffering trying to evaluate this type.

#### Package vs File

Now here's the interesting thing. `@instantdb/admin` is just one file. If *copy and paste* [`index.ts`](https://unpkg.com/@instantdb/admin@0.8.1/src/index.ts) into the project:

```js
import { init } from "./admin.ts";

const { query, transact } = init({
  appId: "your-app-id",
  adminToken: "your-admin-token",
});
```

Then intellisense works:
[image]

My guess here, is that for some reason, when the code is a sibling file, Typescript doesn't generate the giant type.

#### Debugging

I am not 100% sure how to debug this. I tried to reproduce the giant type in a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/PTAEFpK6dv4TAUCUBHArgUwE4E8AVPABywGclLUBFbfFMZJAFxK1AHUALXLAYQA2AQwxl2AXlABvJKFABtANZY8ALlBlmOAJYA7AOYBddZp0HQAH1C6MAWwBGuS6HsB7VwKxDdAbiQBfPxY2UAASAHliZm1XXVBJKTCAfnVEgHceHCx1bl5BETFQfyKg1lJQAGUMe0xcPHjpBV0hW3JiIQBjbI0tPSN1ADkWts6sADUhARLKMvYh1rJ2rompyQiomLirAAp16NjQADJK6tr8AEogvWZcADNR0Fo66Vkm4cXRk16DY1B5keWkz8-hmIQAkrpNN5mOF7AArLAdZgNGRybQAEy+Zn0fjk8mIOFcxCxfV+3jwwNKIQASm1YmJYQikQAeADSABpKh0eLYhAA+Bqs0BYAAeN106LIoGUeFcty5PKErySjQxJPMxWOFW5WF58lZhle6ghUN0MPhiOYVPKYLIAFFbFE8IzLcyCALJARhWKsBKpbSOq4cOjmaY+pzdFgAG64AUqrTYUDqe4CMTW9i0xb0rDhW7M6ic7WKj0vPFCvTSlRyx6-W0Op0ulnUfWGAWi8WS0AJrCvOQqzPEbON5hsws63l8+SGuRydTbAdDvPNg1j4tHUALyE5i0sjkK3X885Tymg8q02yuGOhN0lr3t32d1w75jKxr60AVmXVr1CKV2kUdAIGDolgo6gAARKE4F8r856Xlg14EC2AogrOoAEOmjx0Hgm5iG6q4HiWuE5nmryJO+n5VvKBCwbq8GIchRTsq8RYHkgfKYf+nTMAIeDMgACkIWRmpyfBcNoAjot6HZSoJwnMCWcm+sixyogo5ZxF+8piRJ6K-EK95+pWsrykpZqgCqOmSS2SbWNGuAnsE5R8LEtzaPoKKvEIxDEGCmI9NiuKgEI6K2HoBCuMoujqjiXnENoACq1JgikAV9I5sygAAYhJnjoi5uhuR5kgFUV66JN5iXJTF0xIIBv5SiazDQgAgqFejMqxvIov4ApqYGhXueoOUCHlpXuUFIjMFw6gtRg01BHIA2mBgSJBtsAD6A1Feo436OcpYztN2hkAAdNt7kNAAjMFUrkr2XbiWdU1cA0kZpKAc3Tdsx1nRd+1BSCrxnPUkj5tJD5Sk8+B8tsD0g+oXFIrx+bYZy1B8sxcjnOo-GEmFeHQzhdJbvmBETh6fUPVkzAYDgcQg7dwW6HgryBJQchaN4ZDcQ02x6MQ81iRguiKGQ6hpQYU4HeIVMzqANN03EV1s8ClD1WQUpfa9-WuUN2W5Vg+V67FrzLQma04Ns-3DYbxuDfth2c0950mw0-2AxzoAdFkQg3BFUUNL+eC6B0oDbAeEkxTjoB464BOgWGBiU07CtYLT9MQUI4Gq17MY6LchCRb6QdkCHYc-cX0WS-tuP4ydiffPoKdqXIiuZ+B9g53I7NA7cItIpsH66NoI5dUIPWwzboB7Qdant3E72gE1rXtbonXjvy1sm5cATq-SyKJCDnJc5CvPFJIeij8y5Kw1I3m+f54G3O44GciFYW6AHvrqJ3Qngf4c4SBg6h1AP3UO+w4g4BFtsOeoAzYH1AKDYKaQhCj3QNhbYUhii-mZngXeQMgA), but was not able to do this.

So, *why* is the `index.d.ts` producing such a giant query expansion? Is there any way I can "force" a repro inside a playground?

Comment: Would you please provide your typescript configurations of your library and your project?

Comment: Hey Arash! This is the `tsconfig` for @instantdb/admin: https://unpkg.com/@instantdb/admin@0.8.1/tsconfig.json